# Rendering a shader on WebcamTexture

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

I'm using the following code in my shader file.

```
Shader "Custom/FakeAR"
{
    Properties{
        _MainTex("", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector]_FOV("FOV", Range(1, 2)) = 1.6
        [HideInInspector]_Disparity("Disparity", Range(0, 0.3)) = 0.1
        [HideInInspector]_Alpha("Alpha", Range(0, 2.0)) = 1.0
    }

    SubShader{

        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            // Default Vertex Shader 
            v2f vert(appdata_img v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = MultiplyUV(UNITY_MATRIX_TEXTURE0, v.texcoord.xy);
                return o;
            }

            // Parameters
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _FOV;

            // Alpha is the ratio of pixel density: width to height
            float _Alpha;
            // Disparity is the portion to separate
            // larger disparity cause closer stereovision
            float _Disparity;


            // Fragment Shader: Remap the texture coordinates to combine
            // barrel distortion and disparity video display
            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
                float2 uv1, uv2, uv3;
                float t1, t2;
                float offset;

                // uv1 is the remap of left and right screen to a full screen 
                uv1 = i.uv - 0.5;
                uv1.x = uv1.x * 2 - 0.5 + sign(i.uv.x < 0.5);

                t1 = sqrt(1.0 - uv1.x * uv1.x - uv1.y * uv1.y);
                t2 = 1.0 / (t1 * tan(_FOV * 0.5));

                // uv2 is the remap of side screen with barrel distortion
                uv2 = uv1 * t2 + 0.5;

                // black color for out-of-range pixels
                if (uv2.x >= 1 || uv2.y >= 1 || uv2.x <= 0 || uv2.y <= 0) {
                    return fixed4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                }
                else {
                    offset = 0.5 - _Alpha * 0.5 + _Disparity * 0.5 - _Disparity * sign(i.uv.x < 0.5);
                    // uv3 is the remap of image texture
                    uv3 = uv2;
                    uv3.x = uv2.x * _Alpha + offset;
                    return tex2D(_MainTex, uv3);
                }               
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Im applying this shader on OnRenderImage method as follows,

```
Graphics.Blit(camTextureHolder.mainTexture, nullRenderTexture, shaderMaterial);
```

where `maintexture` of `camTextureHolder` is `WebCamTexture`.

the problem is that the resulting screen is black. I'm expecting to get the processed feed on my display but in turn it displays the scrambled black screeen. Is there any issue with my shader file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
{
     // Copy the source Render Texture to the destination,
     // applying the material along the way.
     Graphics.Blit(camTextureHolder.mainTexture, dest, mat);
}
```